# Is there a way to wrap/offset while drawing to the other side of the image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing

I'm wondering if there's a way to live wrap to the other side of the image while drawing, so if I draw over the left edge of the image it shows up on the right side, and if I draw over the bottom it shows up at the top, etc?

And if not, does anyone have any Mac app suggestions that might do this?

Answer (score 1):

No.

There is the offset filter which allows you to move the image seam to middle of the image. Yes the image does still not wrap around the corner but your problem area is no longer in the corner, as a bonus you can see the seam more visibly. You can then use offset again to reset the state back to where it was.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean like Asteroids, when you fly off the edge of the screen you come back on the opposite side.

There's nothing like this in Photoshop. You'll have to do this manually, by repeating whatever you're making over on the other side.

Comment: that's what I figured, I searched for a while but the offset filter was the only thing I could find. this would be really useful in creating repeating patterns.

Comment: argh, there is a way you could set this up! It would run slow, and use a lot of memory, but if you used instances of symbols you might be able to make this work. The "canvas" would be virtual, not the whole area. Probably need to know a little about Actions and JavaScript to get it working.

Comment: I do know a lot about JS and some about Actions. What's your idea?

Comment: Look up "photoshop smart objects", you can think of them as instances of a parent class. To edit the content of a smart object requires you to edit the original smart object. But if you have a master document with many instances of a smart object, the chance to do what you want emerges. So whatever amount of instances, and whatever transformations you've applied to the instances, the contents only changes when you edit the master object.

Comment: So... theoretically, it would be possible to make a smart object that's bigger than the canvas of your desired master, and then create instances that "reflect" the outside (of canvas) content back onto the other sides.

Comment: interesting thanks for that I'll see what I can figure out